# How to set a dynamic menu in window class in win32?

Tags: c++, winapi

Wndclass requires a menu with lpsz type. It can be assigned using resources - for example makeIntResource(). How can I assign a menu created using createMenu()? It returns HMENU.

Comment: Simple thing is to just use CreateWindow or SetMenu to set the menu.

Comment: In the See Also section of the CreateMenu documentation is a link to SetMenu.

Answer (score 1):

Call [SetMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenu) and pass it your HWND and HMENU.